# Cost of calling `sun.misc.Unsafe` functions in Java?

Tags: java, memory-management

I'm trying to understand the cost of allocating memory off-heap in Java using `Unsafe`.

```java
//This is how I created an Unsafe instance
Field f = Unsafe.class.getDeclaredField("theUnsafe");
f.setAccessible(true);
Unsafe unsafe = (Unsafe) f.get(null);
```

Please help me understand memory allocations in the following code that writes an `int` (4 bytes) off-heap.

```java
long address = unsafe.allocateMemory(Integer.BYTES);
int myInteger = 3;
unsafe.putInt(address, myInteger);
int myReadInt = unsafe.getInt(address);
```

### Cost

- `unsafe.allocateMemory` returns a `long` which gets allocated on JVM. Cost is `8` bytes on JVM for that `long`.
- `int myInteger = 3` is first allocated on heap/stack on the JVM. Cost is `4` bytes on the JVM.
- `unsafe.putInt` then writes `myInteger` off-heap. Cost is `4` bytes off-heap.
- Reading that `int` back out via `unsafe.getInt`, I'm copying that off-heap allocation into JVM which another JVM allocation?

So to write `4` bytes of memory off-heap. I'm allocating `16` bytes in total?

- `8` bytes for `long` address on the JVM ?
- And I'm allocating that `int` twice, once on the JVM and then off-heap?

Am I correct to understand that on the JVM I'm allocating twice as much memory to go off-heap? In `C` or `C++`, this would not be the case?

And to read the integer back out from off-heap, I'm copying that memory back into JVM, which now has to be garbage collected?

If I passed `myInteger = 3` directly to the function, would it by any chance skip the `int` allocation on JVM?

```java
unsafe.putInt(address, 3);
```

Edit: As pointed out by Joachim in the comments, stack allocation is efficient. The question is more about cost of total memory allocation instead of efficiency, that `int` could be replaced with some `Object` that is heap allocated or something that is a lot larger than `4` bytes.

Comment: I suggest you don't consider variables on the stack (i.e. local variables) as "allocated". While technically yes, they do obviously require some space, stack space is managed incredibly efficiently and is effectively "free" for most use cases. Also: if you call a method directly with some value, the value *still* needs to be put on the stack (at least at the Java bytecode level, that might not be true once it's compiled to native code, but the same is true for local variables).

Comment: Kinda realised after I posted the question that I should not have used a primitive in my example which is going to be stack allocated. But if I replaced `int` with an `Object` or just `java.lang.Integer`, the question would makes more sense I guess. But in general, the question is about how much does the memory increases regardless of heap or stack allocation or efficiency. From your response I understand that my assumption about memory allocation doubling and plus more is correct?

Comment: `int` vs. `Object` doesn't really matter, since the local variable of type `Object` is just a reference and will be about the size of an `int` or `long` (depending on the platform and JVM settings). The "doubling" that you talk about makes sense in *some* way, but is really misleading, because half of it (the Java side) depends on what you continue doing with it. And if you don't hold on to the Java side and it gets discarded from the stack or GCed if on the heap, then the "doubling" is no longer true. Usually you'll only ever have a small part of what you allocated off-heap also be on heap.